# Retrieve href value using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve href value from an element as highlighted in the image below. Any suggestions.

Below is the element as an example. I need to retrieve and copy the info in double quotes.

href="mylink.pdf"

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, first find the element with your driver, something like:

```
element = driver.find_element_with_id("ct100...etc...")

hrefText = element.get_attribute("href")
```

Next time, do not paste an image of code.

Comment: Thanks Anand.. It helped and will take care of the suggestions going forward.

Comment: Great! Could you mark this answer as the correct one please?